# How to add custom js function to kendo toolbar button?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using kendo toolbar for menu items in my project. I have a menu named  "New" and under this there are several sub menus.

I want to add a function to the click of the sub menues, so that I can redirect the page accordingly. Here is my code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < subMenues.length; i++) {

            if (subMenues[i].Visible) {

                var tObject = {};
                var imageSource = ResolveUrl(subMenues[i].Image);
                var actionurl = ResolveUrl(subMenues[i].ActionURL);

                tObject['text'] = "<img src='" + imageSource + "'/> " + subMenues[i].Name;                    
                tObject['click'] = function (e) {
                    alert(i);
                };

                //tObject['template'] = '#= ButtonClickHandler(1)#';
                items.push(tObject);
            }
        }

        return items;
```

But here on click of the sub menus each time I am getting the last index of `i` that is 8.

Comment: Can you create a simple example in http://dojo.telerik.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this. Here is my code that adds the client side function

```
 for (var i = 0; i < subMenues.length; i++) {

            if (subMenues[i].Visible) {

                var tObject = {};
                var imageSource = ResolveUrl(subMenues[i].Image);
                var actionurl = ResolveUrl(subMenues[i].ActionURL);

                tObject['text'] = "<img src='" + imageSource + "'/> " + subMenues[i].Name;
                tObject['id'] = actionurl;
                tObject['click'] = ButtonClickHandler;

                items.push(tObject);
            }
        }
```